# Dynamically look for corresponding element in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, macros, vba

Currently I have a pivot table of the form

```
Employee No.   Hours
101010         150
12456          140
 etc           etc
```

Now there is another spreadsheet I have which Currently Looks like this

```
Employee No. Name  Level Organization Code Manager Organization Code etc
101010       Bob    CP3    etc         etc   etc        etc
12456        Jane   CP2    etc         etc   etc        etc
```

The second sheet is automatically pulled from a third party software. Unfortunately it does not pull the hours of that employee as well. This report also sometimes jumbles employee numbers in different orders every month so I need something dyanmic while will match the employee No, with the employee No in the pivot table.

For example suppose we have

```
Employee No. Name  Level Organization Code Manager Organization Code etc
101010       Bob    CP3    etc         etc   etc        etc
```

The macro should then look for an Employee No of the given row we are at in the pivot table.  Basically it will save  `101010` in memory, and loop through the pivot table. Find the matching Employee No and add another column labeled hours with the respective hour for that row.

The desired spreadsheet will look like

```
Employee No. Name  Level  Hours  Organization Code Manager Organization Code etc
101010       Bob    CP3    150         etc         etc   etc        etc
12456        Jane   CP2    140        etc         etc   etc        etc
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried using VLOOKUP() ?   That should work here.

Comment: Yes I've been manually using VLOOKUP for a while. Do you think I could implement a macro that I could implement on next months dataset? I was worried because Names often get jumbled and I fear if I record myself doing the VLOOKUP, it will mess up because the names will be assorted in a different manner in the next dataset

Comment: I.E I would at the end of the day like this to be done via automation

Comment: You can take the hours from the employee in the pivot table directly through calling Getpivotdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "Eno" in stead of "Employee No." assuming that we are on row 2 the pivot table resides starts at AA1 and Eno in the A column, in the Hours column insert the formula `=GETPIVOTDATA("Hours",$AA$1;"Eno",A2)`

[image: Formula row shows J6]

Comment: But what if the employee I'd are scattered? What if Employee 12345 is in position 50 in the pivot table, and 1st in the actual spreadsheet. The software I use to get the sheet orders them at random. I need to get hours by searching an ID

Comment: No worries, the last argument to GETPIVODATA in my example reads the EmpNo and GETPIVOTDATA looks it up for you in the pivot table *regardless of how the table is sorted*. The only thing you need to get the Hours for the employee is that the EmpNo is shown and not filtered away in the pivot table.

Comment: Sorry, could you add a small picture? I think that would help me visualize this

Comment: Input data in table to the left, pivot table from this in the middle and your output table to the right containing only one example row though with the call to Getpiv... shown in J6

Comment: So should I just record a macro of me doing this, so it will automate for the next report?

Comment: I just thought you should insert the formula in my J column in your Hour-column in your report sheet, but you can have a VBA macro fill it in as well

Comment: Unfortunately someone else is going for this role, and they strongly want this process to be done by a click. The only problem is, is that people are added as employees all the time at a large corporation. So I somehow need to account for newly added entries